# Erro Call to undefined function split()

Tags: php, javascript, aplicação-web

Tudo em meu codigo aparenta estar correto porem o erro: "Call to undefined function split()" é me apresentado na tela ao executar meu script pelo que vi o erro está na linha 31 como posso resolver isso ?

```
if(isset($_POST['lista']) && $_POST['delimitador'])
{
    separar(trim($_POST['lista']), $_POST['delimitador']);
}
function separar($lista, $delimitador){
$ab = split("\n", $lista); //está é a linha 31 aonde o erro e apresentado
$cb = count($ab);
for($x = 0; $x < $cb; $x++){
    list($card, $mes, $ano, $cvv) = split("\\".$delimitador, $ab[$x]);
    testar($card, $mes, $ano, $cvv);
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}
}
function getStr($string,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$string);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}
```

Comment: tente dar um caracter de escape faça assim \\n

Comment: Altere split para str_split. De acordo com a documentação split: Esta função está OBSOLETA no PHP 5.3.0 e foi REMOVIDA no PHP 7.0.0.
Alternativas a esta função incluem: preg_split(), explode(), str_split()

Comment: ha sim, obrigado pela informação amigo irei tentar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função [split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) foi removida do php7. A mais próxima é `explode()` ou `preg_split()`.

Mude as linhas:

```
$ab = split("\n", $lista);
list($card, $mes, $ano, $cvv) = split("\\".$delimitador, $ab[$x]);
```

Para:

```
$ab = explode("\n", $lista);
list($card, $mes, $ano, $cvv) = explode("\\".$delimitador, $ab[$x]);
```

Comment: o erro antigo sumiu porem um novo e apresentado Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: @BrunoLazarine em qual linha acontece?

Comment: Linha 34 list($card, $mes, $ano, $cvv) = explode("\\".$delimitador, $ab[$x]);